# Simple Angular 9 project compiles whole Angular Material (es2015 as esm2015)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've created a simple Angular 9 project with only few simple components. I've added angular material using:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

And after I've done it I run **npm start** and noticed it started to compile the whole @angular with a bunch of @angular/material/* components that I don't use in my app:

```
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/bottom-sheet : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015
```

My question is: why it happened? Why does that need to happen?

Before having @angular/material in my project nothing like that had to happen on running **npm start**. Here is my **app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentCompComponent,
    ChildCompComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This is the ngcc compiler preparing your imported modules for Ivy. This is normal. It doesn’t mean all those components will end up in you application - no worries!

Comment: thank you for answer @MikeOne - however is this not going to extend prod build process? and what do you mean by "imported modules"? in fact I havent imported most of them anywhere, only declared material as dependency in package.json

Comment: Depends if you build process is in a seperate CI pipeline. It only does this process once (for every newly installed package). If you want to know more about it, this is a good article: https://dev.to/eugeniolentini/an-introduction-to-angular-9-ivy-compiler-177n

Comment: @MikeOne so I understand it happens because Angular 9 introduced Ivy compiler enabled by default, right? it compiles es2015 code to esm2015? what esm2015 is? I will read the art you linked, thanks!

Comment: and answering the build process question - yes, build is triggered in CI tool, everytime from scratch

Comment: Yeah that step takes slightly longer, however, the rest of the build is slightly faster. I'm not seeing that much difference in build times between v8 and v9..

Answer (score 17):

In tsconfig.json at the:

- lib array add es2015.
- Target change to es2015

[image]

Hope it works for you.